# Proof and meaning of x'' being minimal in orthogonal projections of the form x = x' + x''

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthogonality, projection

I am reading the book Self-organizing maps by Kohonen.

In Theorem 1.1.1 he states

> Of all decompositions of the form $x = x' + x''$ where $x'\in
>  \mathcal{L}$, the one into orthogonal projections has the property
> that $||x''||$ is minimum.

First question is, what does he mean by "minimum"? I have learned Math in a different language from English, so I am not quite sure, what he means by that.

He goes on with the proof

> To prove this theorem, use is made of the definition $||x'|| =
>  (x',x')$ and the facts that $\hat{x} - x' \in \mathcal{L}$, $\quad x - \hat{x} = \tilde{x} \perp \mathcal{L}$,
> whereby $(\hat{x} - x', x - \hat{x}) = 0$. The following expansion then yields

Until here I am still understanding where he is going. Since both $\hat{x}, x' \in \mathcal{L}$ then the difference also must be $\in \mathcal{L}$. The part $\hat{x} = \tilde{x} \perp \mathcal{L}$ is basically the definition of the orthogonal projection, so I am also fine with this. And $(\hat{x} - x', x - \hat{x}) = 0$ basically means that both expressions are orthogonal to each other. $(x,y)$ is defined as the dot-product.

Now he continues with something I don't get how he gets from the second part to the third part of the equation.

> $||x-x'||^2 = (x-\hat{x} + \hat{x} -x',x-\hat{x} + \hat{x} -x') =
>  ||x-\hat{x}||^2 + ||\hat{x}-x'||^2$

He finishes the proof with

> Because the squared norms are always positive or zero, there can be
> written  $ ||x - x'||^2 \geq ||x - \hat{x}||^2 $, from which it is
> directly seen that $x'' = x - x'$ is minimum for $x' = \hat{x}$
> whereby $x'' = \tilde{x} \quad \square$

I am not quite sure if I get the last part correctly, since I don't understand the part before correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the Pythagorean theorem: if $a\perp b$, then $\|a+b\|^2=\|a\|^2+\|b\|^2$ because
$$(a+b,\,a+b)=(a,a)+(a,b)+(b,a)+(b,b)=(a,a)+(b,b)$$
since $(a,b)=(b,a)=0$.

Apply it for $a=x-\hat x$ and $b=\hat x-x'$.

Comment: Thank you, that is very insightful. Could you maybe add what is meant by $x'$ is minimum?

Comment: It's meaning just the inequality $\|x-x'\|\ge\|x-\hat x\|$.